# On a curious equation regarding odd perfect numbers

Tags: number-theory, inequality, upper-lower-bounds, divisor-sum, perfect-numbers

Let $p^k m^2$ be an odd perfect number (OPN) with special prime $p$ satisfying $p \equiv k \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ and $\gcd(p,m)=1$.

Since $\gcd(p^k, \sigma(p^k))=1$, then we essentially get the equation
$$\frac{\sigma(m^2)}{p^k}=\frac{D(m^2)(p-1)}{p^k - 1},$$
where $\sigma(x)$ is the classical sum of divisors of the positive integer $x$, and $D(x)=2x-\sigma(x)$ is the deficiency of $x$.

We derive
$$\frac{\sigma(m^2)}{p^k}=\sigma(m^2) - D(m^2)(p-1) = \sigma(m^2) - 2(p-1)m^2 + (p-1)\sigma(m^2)$$
$$=2(1-p)m^2 + p\sigma(m^2)=\Bigg(I(m^2)-\frac{2(p-1)}{p}\Bigg)\cdot{pm^2},$$
where $I(x)=\sigma(x)/x$ is the abundancy index of $x$.

Here is my question:

> Is it then possible to get a positive lower bound on the quantity
> $$I(m^2)-\frac{2(p-1)}{p}?$$

Note that I know the following facts:

**(1)** $\sigma(m^2)/p^k \geq 315$ by a result of Broughan, Delbourgo, and Zhou.

**(2)** $2(p-1)/p < I(m^2) \leq 2p/(p+1)$ follows from $(p+1)/p \leq I(p^k) < p/(p-1)$

Comment: FYI : We have $I(m^2)-\dfrac{2(p-1)}{p}=\dfrac{2(p-1)}{p(p^{k+1}-1)}:=f(k,p)$ with $\dfrac{\partial f(k,p)}{\partial k}\lt 0, \dfrac{\partial f(k,p)}{\partial p}\lt 0$ and $\displaystyle\lim_{k\to\infty}f(k,p)=\lim_{p\to \infty}f(k,p)=0$.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, @mathlove. Please post that as an answer so that I can upvote it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On OP's request, I am converting my comment into an answer.

FYI :

$I(m^2)-\dfrac{2(p-1)}{p}$ can be written as

$$I(m^2)-\frac{2(p-1)}{p}=\frac{\sigma(m^2)}{m^2}-\frac{2(p-1)}{p}=\frac{2p^k}{\sigma(p^k)}-\frac{2(p-1)}{p}$$
$$=\frac{2p^k(p-1)}{p^{k+1}-1}-\frac{2(p-1)}{p}=\frac{2p^{k+1}(p-1)-2(p-1)(p^{k+1}-1)}{p(p^{k+1}-1)}=\frac{2(p-1)}{p(p^{k+1}-1)}$$

Let $f(k,p):=\dfrac{2(p-1)}{p(p^{k+1}-1)}$.

Then, we have $$\dfrac{\partial f(k,p)}{\partial k}\lt 0,\qquad \dfrac{\partial f(k,p)}{\partial p}\lt 0$$
and
$$\lim_{k\to\infty}f(k,p)=\lim_{p\to \infty}f(k,p)=0$$

Comment: Note that $$f(1,p)=\frac{2}{p(p+1)}>0$$ for *each* $p$.

Answer (score 0):

This answer offers another perspective for the problem at hand.

---

[Dris (2012)](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/journals/JIS/VOL15/Dris/dris8.html) showed that
$$\frac{\sigma(m^2)}{p^k} > 1 \tag{1}$$
must necessarily hold.

But note that we have
$$\frac{\sigma(m^2)}{p^k} = \Bigg(I(m^2) - \frac{2(p-1)}{p}\Bigg)\cdot{pm^2} \tag{2}$$

Inequality $(1)$ and Equation $(2)$ together imply that
$$\Bigg(I(m^2) - \frac{2(p-1)}{p}\Bigg)\cdot{pm^2} > 1$$
so that we finally obtain
$$I(m^2) - \frac{2(p-1)}{p} > \frac{1}{pm^2} \tag{3}$$

Notice that
$$\varepsilon = \frac{1}{pm^2} > 0,$$
albeit **very small**.